# Econometrics OLS estimates

Tags: regression

**I cant seem to use the formula to calculate B1 without knowing xi and yi. Is it possible to calculate using just the variances and covariance? Please help!**

The classical linear regression model

1. Suppose you believe there is a linear relationship between a vehicle’s fuel 
   consumption (Fi, measured in litres/100km) and its speed (Si, measured in km/hour):
   Fi = β0 + β1.Si + εi.

Suppose you have a random sample of 46 observations on (Fi,Si), with the following sample 
statistics:      Fi = β0 + β1.Si + εi.

Suppose you have a random sample of 46 observations on (Fi,Si), with the following sample statistics: Fbar=8 Sbar=90  Var(Fi)=2  Var(Si)=2500 and Cov(Fi,Si)=-250

(a) What are the OLS estimates of β0 and β1.  Interpret these estimates.

Answer (score 1):

Use this relationship: $E(Y|X=x)=\mu_y + \rho \frac{\sigma_2}{\sigma_1}(x-\bar{x})$, which
appears in most of the probability textbooks. The answer will fall out of it.